# Not able to set value back to angular select dropdown on page load

Tags: angular

Hello Angular Champs,

I have a dropdown I am able to save selected dorp down value in session storage.  While loading back that component not able to select that value in dropdown.

html code

```
<div>
  <div>
    <select id="customer_slct" #customerSelected>
      <option value="{{customer.customerId}}" *ngFor="let customer of customerList">{{customer.name}} 
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" id="refreshCust" (click)="changeCustomer(customerSelected.value)">Refresh Customer<button>
  </div>
</div>
```

component ts file.

```
ngOnInit(){
this.selectedCustomer = sessionStorage.getItem("selectedCustomer");
$('#customerSelected').val(this.selectedCustomer);//This didnt work. 
//I need to selected customer number in the dropdown which was selected be4 page refresh.
}

changeCustomer(newCustomer:string){
  sessionStorage.setItem("selectedCustomer",newCustomer);
  window.location.reload();//I want to reload all componenets with new customer details.
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use two way data binding with `[(ngModel)]`? Or `ViewChild` instead of `$('#customerSelected')`?

Comment: I am adding a new dropdown to an existing application. ngModel is not being used in this entire application. not sure why but, this is how it was designed.

Comment: omg your using jquery.

Comment: You should try to avoid using jquery in angular,.Angular has lot of options and features for your requirement. Make sure you go through angular docs and online sites to check if there is a feature for your requirement in angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
  <div>
    <select id="customer_slct" #customerSelected [(ngModel)]="selectedCustomer">
      <option value="{{customer.customerId}}" *ngFor="let customer of customerList">{{customer.name}} 
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" id="refreshCust" (click)="changeCustomer(customerSelected.value)">Refresh Customer<button>
  </div>
</div>
```

component ts file.

```
ngOnInit(){
this.selectedCustomer = sessionStorage.getItem("selectedCustomer");
}

changeCustomer(newCustomer:string){
  sessionStorage.setItem("selectedCustomer",newCustomer);
  window.location.reload();//I want to reload all componenets with new customer details.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments you should use two-way data binding for your application, which is the ideal solution.

Just to tell you, the issue in your code is you are using wrong identifier to select an element by ID. You need to use this line:

```
$('#customer_slct').val(this.selectedCustomer);
```

Comment: are you getting any error in console? Can i tell you ngModel approach ?

Comment: There is no error, dropdown has a default value, Yes Please, will try ngmodel

Comment: Can you please tell me the value of this.selectedCustomer when you execute this line this.selectedCustomer = sessionStorage.getItem("selectedCustomer");. Just to inform you, you already have code ngModel

Comment: Its just variable. to hold values in that component.

Comment: I won't be able to help without stackblitz